# Chainlink Keepers UpkeepRegistrationRequest Contract

Tags: solidity, oracles, chainlink

Alright I was going through the keepers contract to understand how it works from a contract perspective.
There are two parameters that I don't understand what they're used for in the `register` function which is the uint96 `amount` and the uint8 `source` if anyone could help out if you know what they're for that'd be awesome.

```
  function register(
    string memory name,
    bytes calldata encryptedEmail,
    address upkeepContract,
    uint32 gasLimit,
    address adminAddress,
    bytes calldata checkData,
    uint96 amount,
    uint8 source
  ) external onlyLINK {
    require(adminAddress != address(0), "invalid admin address");
    bytes32 hash = keccak256(abi.encode(upkeepContract, gasLimit, adminAddress, checkData));

    emit RegistrationRequested(
      hash,
      name,
      encryptedEmail,
      upkeepContract,
      gasLimit,
      adminAddress,
      checkData,
      amount,
      source
    );

    AutoApprovedConfig memory config = s_config;
    if (config.enabled && _underApprovalLimit(config)) {
      _incrementApprovedCount(config);

      _approve(name, upkeepContract, gasLimit, adminAddress, checkData, amount, hash);
    } else {
      uint96 newBalance = s_pendingRequests[hash].balance.add(amount);
      s_pendingRequests[hash] = PendingRequest({admin: adminAddress, balance: newBalance});
    }
  }
```

In the natspec the details of the params were...

```
@param amount quantity of LINK upkeep is funded with (specified in Juels)
@param source application sending this request
```

I have no idea what a juels is and what they mean by application sending the request as a uint8 parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `source` param is not used except for internal metrics.  You will not need to use that.

The `amount` param specifies amount of LINK, and the smallest denomination of LINK is a Juels.  The Juels is to Link what Wei is to Ether. The Juels is named after one of the cofounders and the Chief Scientist at Chainlink Labs ([reference](https://www.arijuels.com/)).